# Promises Array executing incorrectly

Tags: javascript, promise, jquery-deferred

I am trying to execute the success function once all the promises are resolved.. But the success function is executed before the promises get resolved. Sufggest what is wrong in my code.

```
var loadImg = function(imageUrls, success, failure) {
    var promises = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < imageUrls.length; i++) {
        (function(url, promise) {
            var img = new Image();
            img.onload = function() {
                promise.resolve();
            };
            img.onerror = function() {
                promise.reject();
            };
            img.src = url;
        }(imageUrls[i], promises[i] = $.Deferred()));
    }
    $.when.apply($, promises).done(success, failure);

}
```

Comment: Seems to work just fine for me, other than the `done` callback, which doesn't have a `failure` argument, the second callback would simply be called on success of the second image etc. what you probably wanted was `.apply($, promises).done(success).fail(failure);`

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/adeneo/gn7pj5ow/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you'd like to wait for a collection of Promises to complete before performing some action, I would recommend [Promise.all](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all)

---

**make life easy**

First we'll make a `loadImage` utility function that takes a url and returns a `Promise` of an `HTMLImageElement`

From there, we just map over your array of url strings using our new `loadImage` utility – this results in an array of Promises, which is exactly what `Promise.all` is expecting.

```
// loadImage :: String -> Promise<HTMLImageElement>
const loadImage = url => {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    var img = new Image()
    img.src = url
    img.onload = () => resolve(img)
    img.onerror = (err) => reject(err)
  })
}

const imageUrls = ['a.jpg', 'b.jpg', 'c.jpg', 'd.jpg']

Promise.all(imageUrls.map(loadImage)).then(
  images => console.log(images), // [<img src='a.jpg'>, <img src='b.jpg'>, ...]
  err => console.error(err)
)
```

The `loadImage` is a great first step because it gives us a generic way to load images using promises at any point in our program. Each time we need an image, we don't need to manually construct promises to deal with the loading. Just call `loadImage(someUrl)` and now you can work with your promised image.

Notice, we don't even need an explicit loop now. We can use other built-in looping mechanism like `map` or `forEach` and everything just works as expected. By writing a little utility function like this, we write way less code in the end.

*Warning:* no images will be displayed if any *one* of them fails to load correctly.

---

**practical use**

Presumably, you'd want to append the images to your document somehow, so instead of `console.log`, maybe something like this

```
// loadImagesForElement :: (HTMLElement, [String]) -> Promise<[HTMLImageElement]>
const loadImagesForElement = (target, imageUrls) => {
  return Promise.all(imageUrls.map(loadImage)).then(
    images => images.forEach(i => target.appendChild(i)),
    err => console.error(err)
  )
}

loadImagesForElement(document.body, ['a.jpg', 'b.jpg', 'c.jpg'])
// => Promise { ... }
```

---

**using jQuery Deferred**

This translates to jQuery's Deferred pretty easily if that's what you're looking for – changes in **bold**

```
// loadImage :: String -> Promise<HTMLImageElement>
const loadImage = url => {
  let d = $.Deferred()
  var img = new Image()
  img.src = url
  img.onload = () => d.resolve(img)
  img.onerror = (err) => d.reject(err)
  return d.promise()
}

// loadImagesForElement :: (HTMLElement, [String]) -> Promise<[HTMLImageElement]>
const loadImagesForElement = (target, imageUrls) => {
  return $.when(...imageUrls.map(loadImage)).then(
    (...images) => images.forEach(i => target.appendChild(i)),
    err => console.error(err)
  )
}
```

If you cannot rely on spread syntaxes, things get just a little bit uglier – changes in **bold**

```
// loadImagesForElement :: (HTMLElement, [String]) -> Promise<[HTMLImageElement]>
const loadImagesForElement = (target, imageUrls) => {
  return $.when.apply($, imageUrls.map(loadImage)).then(
    function(/* images */) {
      Array.prototype.forEach.call(arguments, i => target.appendChild(i))
    },
    err => console.error(err)
  )
}
```

Comment: I tried this but the success function is not firing.
https://jsbin.com/rilixaxova/edit?js,console,output

Comment: @Vinny You forgot `img.src = url;` so the promises were never settled